# Images don't load on safari

Tags: php, wordpress, image, browser, safari

The site works fine on all other browsers, but yesterday on safari the images stoped loading. Most of them were blurry and some didnt load at all. The blurry ones started loading by removing the params from the image but the ones that didn't load at all i can't figure out why. They all have data-src-square.

Code:

```
    <div class="card__image"
    data-src-square="<?php echo esc_url( $square_featured_image['urlTemplate'] ); ?>"
    data-src="<?php echo esc_url( $featured_image['urlTemplate'] ); ?>"
    style="background-image:url(<?php echo esc_url( $featured_image['urlTemplate_small'] ); ?>"
    alt="<?php echo $featured_image['alt']; ?>)">
    </div>
```

And on the safari browser if i inspect the html it has an empty `" "` which doesn't happen on the other browsers:

[image: Any ideia how i can fix this/why this happens?]

Comment: can you show the full inspect of element, we can't see evrything

Comment: Yes, sorry i'll update the image.

Comment: why alt tag for div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The background-image image url is missing **)** in the end. It seems safari is more strict.

```
style="background-image:url(<?php echo esc_url( $featured_image['urlTemplate_small'] ); ?>)"
```